# How to create pagination like behavior for an array in javascript

Tags: jquery, arrays

In my application after getting my application Authorized by Facebook I get all their friends info which is returned in an array.

I sort this array in order of the friends whose birthday is closest to the current date.(code not shown for this)

I want to display the information for 20  friends at a time as some users may have hundreds of friends.

Currently I am putting all of the friends on the page at one time.

Here is the code I was using to loop through the entire array and put the info on the page

```
$.each(json.data,function(i,fb){

                  var pic_url = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+fb.id+"/picture";
                  json_details = {name: fb.name, provider_user_id: fb.id, birthday: fb.birthday, provider_name : 'Facebook' }; 
                  var celebrant_details = escape(JSON.stringify(json_details) );
                  html += "<form id='new_celebration"+fb.id+"' method='post' action='/celebrations' accept-charset='UTF-8'>";
                  html += "<input type='hidden' id='friend' value='"+celebrant_details +"'  name='celebrant_details'  />"
                  html += "<input type='hidden' id='manager' value='"+manager_details +"'  name='manager_details' />"

                  html += "<li>" + fb.name + "</li>";
                  if(fb.birthday != null){  html += "<li>" + fb.birthday + "</li>"; } //don't show if don't have a birthday
                  html += "<li><img src="+pic_url+" /></li>";       
                  html += "<input class='button-mini-subtle submit' type='submit' value='select' alt='select'  >";    
                  html += "</form>";

                });//.each loop
```

I am a NOOB so would appreciate some guidance.

I want to give the users a button they can click to display more users from the array. 
So I know I need to create some kind of a function call and I need to know where I am in the array.

How can I get this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a extra `index` variable that will hold current index in your array or have the index stored as the jQuery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Then you can use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the subarray.

Here is the simplified example using `.data()`. You have to adapt it to your data structure and required HTML output - that was not your question :).

```
// display our initial list
displayNext();

$("#next").click(function() {
  // display next elements
  displayNext();
});

function displayNext() {
  // get the list element
  var list = $('#list');

  // get index stored as a data on the list, if it doesn't exist then assign 0
  var index = list.data('index') % arr.length || 0;

  // save next index - for next call
  list.data('index', index + 20);

  // 1) get 20 elements from array - starting from index, using Array.slice()
  // 2) map them to array of li strings
  // 3) join the array into a single string and set it as a HTML content of list
  list.html($.map(arr.slice(index, index + 20), function(val) {
    return '<li id=' + val.id + '>' + val.name + '</li>';
  }).join(''));
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/apuwuh/8/edit#javascript,live)** is the code.

Comment: Thanks dzejkej it looks like what I am looking for. I really appreciate you pointing me on the correct path.

Comment: @chell Glad to help :). Good luck with your project!

Comment: Instead of showing the next 20 how could I add the next 20 to the already existing items on the "page"

Comment: @chell Just change `list.html()` to `list.append()`.

Comment: Thanks dzejkej you are a rock star!

Answer (score 1):

Answer Prepared from Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_slice_array)  and [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/apuwuh/8/edit?html,js,output)  and [Kubetz Sol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521203/4425004)

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
            <p>Array Based Pagination</p>
            <button onclick="First()">First</button>
            <button onclick="Previous()">Previous</button>
            <button onclick="Next()">Next</button>
            <button onclick="Last()">Last</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <br />
            <p id="page"></p>
            <br />
            <p id="info"></p>
            <script>
                var arr = [];
                var currentPage = 1;
                var pageSize = 5;
                var skip = 0;
                var totalCount = 0;
                var totalPage = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                    arr.push(i);
                }
                myFunction();

                function First() {
                    currentPage = 1;
                    skip = 0;
                    myFunction();
                }

                function Next() {
                    if (currentPage < totalPage) currentPage++;
                    skip = pageSize * (currentPage - 1);
                    myFunction();
                }

                function Previous() {
                    if (currentPage > 1) currentPage--;
                    skip = pageSize * (currentPage - 1);
                    myFunction();
                }

                function Last() {
                    currentPage = totalPage;
                    skip = pageSize * (currentPage - 1);
                    myFunction();
                }

                function myFunction() {
                    totalCount = arr.length;
                    totalPage = Math.ceil(totalCount / pageSize);
                    var citrus = arr.slice(skip, skip + pageSize);
                    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "skip: " + skip + ", CP: " + currentPage + ", pageSize: " + pageSize;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = citrus;
                    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = "Page Info: " + currentPage + "/" + totalPage;
                }
            </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```

My Above Code Demo @ [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FR1FSPP1K5MT)